# How to use % in a equation without deleting the rest of the equation?

Tags: equations

I'm still pretty new to LaTeX and TeX. I came across this equation on GCD.

[image: GCD equation]

I wanted to note it down. So, I wrote the equation like this:

```
\begin{equation*}
 gcd(a,b)=
   \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        a, & b=0\\
       gcd(b, a % b) , & b \neq 0
    \end{array}\right.
 \end{equation*}
```

But no matter how hard I try, I always get this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you just want to print the symbol, then you need `\%`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `%` is TeX's comment character, and TeX ignores everything afterward.  Somewhat like `#` or `//` in some programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

As @Luis Turcio suggested, you can simply just put a `\` in front of the `%` symbol. So you would use `\%` to typeset it.

All in all, the full equation would look like this:

```
\begin{equation*}
 gcd(a,b)=
   \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        a, & b=0\\
       gcd(b, a \% b) , & b \neq 0
    \end{array}\right.
 \end{equation*}
```

But as @David Carlisle has said, you should "never set multi-letter symbols in math italic." So we would have to put `\` in front of `gcd`. In addition, it's a good idea to use the `cases` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package} for the math expression at hand. And we would have this:

```
\begin{equation*}
\gcd(a,b)=
    \begin{cases}
        a,               & b=0 \\
        \gcd(b, a \% b), & b \neq 0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```